# node multer posting form data with postman - no body received

Tags: node.js, postman, multer

I am using the example given here: `https://github.com/expressjs/multer`. However instead of using the form in the example, I am using Postman to POST some data, however I am getting an empty body. I have set Postman to use `form-data`. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Quoting the documentation: `"Don't forget the enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form."`. This information is in the link you provided. Just above the code example.

Comment: please add postman screenshots

Comment: hi, have added postman screenshots , thanks

Comment: It is supposed to be in your `req.body`, can you try to look at that location?